# Calling unknown settings

Tags: c#, settings.settings

C# Project in Visual Studio 2013

I need to build a X-Walk (cross reference) between a database's field names and a list of 'Standard' names.

Because this list needs to be maintained and occasionally updated, my inclination is to create a Settings class and then call the setting to get the cross reference. 
e.g.

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("SIZE")]
public string MySize {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["MySize"]));
    }
}
```

and then it would obviously be called thus:

```
private string str = MyProject.AttributeXref.Default.MySize;
```

Here is where the rub comes... at run-time the code I have to respond to will be passing the 'Attributes' by name and I have to perform the lookup. If all I have is 'MySize' and not 
`MyProject.AttributeXref.Default.MySize;`

should I be doing something similar to
`MyProject.AttributeXref.{0}`

Or...
Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

and the answer is...

```
var a = "MySize";
var b = MyProject.AttributeXref[a];
Console.WriteLine("MySize = " + b);
```

Output - MySize = SIZE